# How to display the text "\n" in an XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

My problem is quite simple.  I would like to print "\n" in an android application XML Layout using a TextView.
The code I'm using takes it to the next line.
My code:

android:text="abc\nxyz"

OUTPUT:
abc
xyz

DESIRED OUTPUT:
abc\nxyz

I'm just a beginner, so excuse me if the terminology I use is incorrect.

Comment: Try `android:text="abc\\nxyz"` You need to escape \

Comment: I use it like this in a string resource and it works: `<string name="myString">abc\n123</string>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was fast. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double backslash `\\n` or the ASCII equivalent `&#92;n` to display "`\n`" in your xml